# Patching a kubernetes deployment for livenessProbe

Tags: kubernetes, patch

So at work we are having a bit of a mare with Helm and Kubernetes.

Long-term we have a fix, but short-term we have some patches that I'm currently manually applying using `kubectl edit deployment -n {namespace} {podBaseName}`, then editing in vim...

It feels a bit cowboy.

I found https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/ which suggests I can issue a `kubectl patch deployment -n {namespace} {podBaseName} --patch 'some: patch: definition'`

I'm looking to add to a `livenessProbe` but I'm not 100% sure of the Syntax to ensure I only add the property I want, which is `initialDelaySeconds: 60`

Is it also possible to `upsert` using a patch if I wanted to add `startupProbe` or `readinessProbe`?

Comment: Gutted to find out I cannot specify a namespace and use `--selector=tier=worker,app=appname'` to update all pods with a specific type. This is possible with `kubectl set env`

Comment: Do I understand correctly there's no `initialDelaySeconds` set at all? So you want to add it and not to modify?

Comment: In some cases it will be set, and in other cases the entire `livenessProbe` should be inserted. I actually got this far yesterday. Now my issue seems to be applying it to multiple containers and pods. And ensuring it only targets specific container types within a pod.

Answer (score 1):

So this is as far as I have got.

It does solve some problems (mostly not going via vim as the `kubectl edit deployment` leads to, with possible user-error etc).

Our Helm is still broken, and I've no definitive ETA on the fix.

So The current `kubectl` fix/hack is limited (or seems to be) limited to single container pod type.

```
kubectl patch deployment \
    -n ${KUBE_NAMESPACE} \
    ${KUBE_POD_PREFIX} \
    --patch '{"spec":{"containers":[{"livenessProbe":{"exec":{"command":["your", "health", "check", "command"]},"failureThreshold":5,"initialDelaySeconds":60,"periodSeconds:5,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":1},"name":"sqs-worker"}]}}}}'
```

This is to patch an sqs-worker type container in a pod, which only has that container. We also have web-containers which have an nginx ingress as well as an instance of an app.

`KUBE_NAMESPACE` is how we are separating internal environments. This might be a branch name or `prod` or `dev`. `kubectl get namespaces` should be your guide to picking a value for you.

`KUBE_POD_PREFIX` is the pod name, without the odd suffix that is appended. This might be helm or our helm related. All I know is I might have `service-a-specific-task-worker-sdhhdg3jh` pod and I supply `service-a-specific-task-worker`. I use `kubectl get pods -n ${KUBE_NAMESPACE}` as my source of truth here.

Comment: Ideally is to put everything in `json` or `yaml` file and use it as `kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch "$(cat patch-file.json)"` like it's described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#alternate-forms-of-the-kubectl-patch-command) for consistency purposes.

Comment: That link is part of the same page and shows the same method but using `--patch` with the OS/Shell `cat` utility. I did some looking and this is why I chose to keep the contents as a string. Although I am aware of `--patch-file` which I'd assume avoids that step.

Comment: Update, is that I should have been using `kubectl get deployments -n ${KUBE_NAMESPACE}` to find the value, as it may not be the same as the pod prefix that we wish to patch. More broadly, this was due to a helm problem with numeric values being "stringified" incorrectly. Fixing in helm, by using a different CLI argument helped, but this patching of kubernetes is my preference for a patch and minimal reproducible example, as it only infers kubernetes, not other container native technologies, that not everyone uses.